# MySQL not deleting records

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a form to delete rows in a table, but I am getting everything done but the row deletion. It clears all value in the table but it does not delete the row or ID. I have tried committing it

PHP Script

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Setting up the Database Connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Fh3dSWIWCLd4";
$dbname = "servers";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Capturing the POST Data
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

// Executing the SQL statement
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header("Location:http://osgaming.joec.pw/login/");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "
" . $conn->error;
}
// Closing the database connection
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

HTMLform

```
<?php include 'sql-dbsv-del.php'; ?>
<h2><b class="e">Delete Entries</b></h2> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="form-group">
<label for="id">Database ID</label>
<input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Database ID"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete Entry" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

https://gyazo.com/ca3f10f862b3993f5d716cb49242304b
There is an image to what it is doing to the variable in the database

Comment: Is the `ID` column a `string` or an `integer`? You should set `id=4` if it's an integer, otherwise `id='4'` if it's a string.

Comment: use prepared statements instead of direct injecting parameters into query. This `"DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='.$id.' LIMIT 1";` make your system vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Echo $sql and see if id is posted.

Comment: Please tell me the UserID, Password and Site you have listed are not "correct values" which could be used to gain application level access...to the db..

Comment: DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='.4.' LIMIT 1
What I get from echo $sql;

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but it's probably a good idea to have `s around your database, table, and field names. That way you won't have to worry about MySQL errors if you ever name a database, table, or field name the same as a keyword.

Comment: remove the dots, you just want `$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";` quotes if its a string, remove them to if its an int

Comment: When I remove the dots it does not affect anything, this includes with quotes and without. It also no longer redirects to the same page I have it too, but to the header where I now commented it out

Comment: Do a `COMMIT` after your `DELETE` and let us know if it helps.

Comment: Commit does nothing else, below is an example of my problem: https://gyazo.com/ca3f10f862b3993f5d716cb49242304b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL PHP Not Deleting Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790955/mysql-php-not-deleting-data)

Answer (score 3):

Learn basic PHP string syntax:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='.$id.' LIMIT 1";
       ^--start of PHP string                       ^---end of PHP string
```

You're generating the literal query string

```
DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='.4.' LIMIT 1
```

Note how your bad attempt at PHP string concatenation actually became part of the query string. you're already **IN** a php string, so you can't execute PHP inside that string - PHP is not recursively embeddable/executable.

Either of these would work:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='" . $id . "' LIMIT 1";
```

but of course, still leave you vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Still isn't quite working, here is what it does: https://gyazo.com/ca3f10f862b3993f5d716cb49242304b

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement here:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='4' LIMIT 1";
```

Is not using your variable `$id` at all.  You are trying to delete id = 4 with every execution.  If that ID doesn't exist, you are silently doing nothing.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change it back, as I was trying to test it out to see if it would work as a number instead of a variable