# MySQL PHP Not Deleting Data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get a form to delete rows in a table, but I am getting everything done but the row deletion. It clears all value in the table but it does not delete the row or ID. I have tried committing it

PHP Script

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Setting up the Database Connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Fh3dSWIWCLd4";
$dbname = "servers";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Capturing the POST Data
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

// Executing the SQL statement
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
header("Location:http://osgaming.joec.pw/login/");
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "
" . $conn->error;
}
// Closing the database connection
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

HTMLform

```
<?php include 'sql-dbsv-del.php'; ?>
<h2><b class="e">Delete Entries</b></h2> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="form-group">
<label for="id">Database ID</label>
<input type="number" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Database ID"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Delete Entry" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

https://gyazo.com/ca3f10f862b3993f5d716cb49242304b
There is an image to what it is doing to the variable in the database

Comment: I distinctly remember seeing this exact question earlier today.

Comment: Edited version, last one wasn't very descriptive

Comment: Use this: $sql = "DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";

Comment: @LaughingQuoll Everything like that was already suggested the first time he asked the question.

Comment: Just tried again for reference and still does not do anything, the id field sill stays for some reason

Comment: If nothing happens try procedural style: mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM sv_info WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

Comment: @developerwjk I did not see that duplicate. Sorry for any inconvenience I may have caused you.

Comment: @LaughingQuoll Lol. No inconvenience to me, just want to give you a heads up so you don't go down a long rabbit trail.

Comment: @developerwjk don't worry. I was just unaware of the duplicate. In fact I was answering the question when it was marked as such.